# How to work with (=true) references in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm building an AngularFire app and I'm struggling with the structure of my database. The app works with users, uploads and comments, much like the Firefeed example, but different. I'm trying to get my database as flat as possible, so I want to keep the uploads apart from the users (if a comment on an upload is posted, it should be updating in every users timeline).

At this moment, if an upload is posted, it goes to the 'uploads' branch, apart from the 'users'. Every user will get the id of that upload as: uploadUid=true in their feed, so the data is not duplicated.

The problem is, how can I get the data from the upload to the users who need that upload on their feed, just by referencing with true? So, for example, how can I loop through the feed of user 1, because I only have "-KGkxzQj0FM2CMAXo5Em" : true", where I need the info from that upload, which is in the 'uploads' branch.

**EDIT:**

```
{
  "uploads" : {
    "-KGkxzQj0FM2CMAXo5Em" : {
      "author" : "87a8b6c8-7f72-45c2-a8c5-bb93fe9d320d",
      "date" : 1462184179564,
      "name" : "Zorro",
      "reasonUpload" : "Test",
      "uploadTitle" : "Title 1",
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "87a8b6c8-7f72-45c2-a8c5-bb93fe9d320d" : {
      "date" : 1459369248532,
      "feed" : {
        "-KGkxzQj0FM2CMAXo5Em" : true
      },
      "followers" : {
        "e3de536b-03a1-4fb4-b637-ebcebaae55c6" : true
      },
      "following" : {
        "e3de536b-03a1-4fb4-b637-ebcebaae55c6" : true
      },
      "regUser" : "87a8b6c8-7f72-45c2-a8c5-bb93fe9d320d",
      "uploads" : {
        "-KGkxzQj0FM2CMAXo5Em" : true
      },
      "name": "Zorro"
   },
    "e3de536b-03a1-4fb4-b637-ebcebaae55c6" : {
      "date" : 1459369285026,
      "feed" : {
        "-KGkxzQj0FM2CMAXo5Em" : true
      },
      "followers" : {
        "87a8b6c8-7f72-45c2-a8c5-bb93fe9d320d" : true
      },
      "following" : {
        "87a8b6c8-7f72-45c2-a8c5-bb93fe9d320d" : true
      },
      "regUser" : "e3de536b-03a1-4fb4-b637-ebcebaae55c6"
    }
  }
}
```

And the structure for how to get a post to every followers feed (this is what Firefeed uses):

```
self._mainUser.child("followers").once("value", function(followerList) {
    followerList.forEach(function(follower) {
      if (!follower.val()) {
        return;
      }
      var childRef = self._firebase.child("users").child(follower.name());
      childRef.child("feed").child(uploadRefId).set(true);
    });
  });
```

**EDIT 2**

And this is what I now use to get to the specific uploadIDs in the feed of each follower (in my controller):

```
firebaseAuth.$onAuth(function (authUser) {
    if (authUser) {
var currentUser1 = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("users").child($rootScope.currentUser.$id);
var firebase = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

currentUser1.child("feed").once("value", function(list) {
                list.forEach(function(follower) {
                    var childRef = firebase.child("uploads").child(follower.key());
//                  childRef.child("feed").push(upload);
                    var childRefArray = $firebaseArray(childRef);
                    $rootScope.feedd = childRefArray;
                });
            });
    } // if(authUser)

}); // auth.$onAuth
```

**EDIT 3**

And in my html:

```
<div class="feed-total" ng-repeat="feed in feedd  | orderBy: '-date'">
<div>
    {{feed.reasonUpload}} // this should be "Test"
</div>
```

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Your code seems to already set the `$uploadId: true` markers. What is the problem? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Thanks Frank! I've now updated my post with the actual JSON as text. The 'true' markers are indeed working, but I can't figure out how to let the user loop through de actual upload information in the 'uploads' branch.